# How to completely style an Angular Bootstrap Component

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, web-component

I would like to know if it is possible to completely take control of the style/css of a component that I'm using from ng-bootstrap?

Here's my problem:

I have this code...

```
<ngb-datepicker
  #dp
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  (navigate)="date = $event.next"
  style="color: black; border: solid 3px red"
></ngb-datepicker>
```

And this is the result...

[image]

But I would like to **change the color of the week days to black instead of being blue**. The "color" property only changes the color of the numbers not the week days and I can't seem to find a way to do it.
Is this even possible?

When I executed the code I inspected the element in hopes of finding some information to help me but my knowledge is very limited so I leave here what I've found in hopes of helping you guys.

[image]

I tried finding a way to style the class "ngb-dp-weekday small" but couldn't figure it out.

**Thank you all in advance!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a deep style in your component stylesheet

```
::ng-deep {
  .ngb-dp-weekday {
    color: black !important;
  }
}
```

[image]

Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sufzp-s1b3rn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-basic.scss) project.

Answer (score 1):

use `::ng-deep` or `:host` directives.

use these features with cautions as this is a bad practice

example:
component.scss

```
::ng-deep{
 selector{
   /* your desired rules */
 }
}
```